# Prusa MK3S 0.8 mm nozzle layers separating

Tags: pla, 3d-models, nozzle

I am currently printing a simple cup out of PLA (I will later anneal it). My nozzle is 0.8 mm and I'm using a 0.4 mm layer height. Unfortunately, the layers keep separating. They don't detach completely, but there are 1 layer-tall, 3-7 mm wide gaps. I increased the temperature, since my speed is 100 mm/s. I also tried decreasing cooling and increasing the flow. This only helped a little bit.

Moreover, small increases in the temperature like 230/240 °C didn't work and now I have to use 270 and even 280 °C, which is crazy, considering my layer height is 0.4 mm. Is there any easy solution that will increase the quality?

Settings:

- Material: PLA
- Layer height: 0.4 mm
- Nozzle: 235 °C first layer, 270 °C for the rest.
- Bed: 60 °C
- Cooling: 62 %
- Speed: 100 mm/s

I have noticed that 280 °C is better for large prints (large area, not height) and small prints look better when I change the temperature to 240/250 °C.
This is how my prints look by now. The extrusion is very inconsistent, with overextrusion in the middle of the layers and gaps in the corners:

[image]

[image]

I suspect that the layer lines are not parallel to the heatbed and are over extruded, because of the high temp. I lowered it to 230 °C and there was no drooping/over extrusion, but there were more 'holes'.

Comment: Is it possible that your hotend cannot keep up with the flow? Hence the large temperature?

Comment: The hotend is the default one that comes with Prusa MK3S. I don't know how powerful it is and I don't know how to check if that's the case. My flow is around 100 now.

Comment: Just for troubleshooting, have you tried printing more slowly?

Comment: Wow, that is smoking hot for PLA ...

Comment: @Aerik I have and it did help. I reduced the speed to 50mm/s and the result was better, but I still think it's too slow. I know someone who could do 100mm/s on the same printer, nozzle and layer height . I saw that a long time ago so I still have no idea how he pulled it off. Also, I changed the nozzle so as to print faster and it turns out that 0.4mm layer height at 50mm/s is far slower than for example 0.3mm at 150mm/s

Comment: Large nozzles can make larger heights but need to be done slower unless you have a more powerful heater or longer meltzone.

Comment: How about you swap in a 0.4 nozzle and see how well the print comes out -- and how long it takes.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I've been using the 0.4mm nozzle for a long time now and the print quality is really nice (on the 0.4mm nozzle). I printed a different version of the current model on 0.3mm layer height and 150mm/s speed and it was really nice. I changed the nozzle for two reasons: faster printng and food safety (brass nozzles have lead, hardened steel ones don't) Unfortunately, I have just run into another problem. I'm getting the THERMAL RUNAWAY error, because my nozzle temp. drops from 280*C to 230*C. What's the cause of that?

Comment: Edit: I fixed the THERMAL RUNAWAY error by placing a small E3D silicon part that protects my nozzle&hotend from excessive cooling caused by the part cooling fan.

Answer (score 1):

After printing ~30 calibration test cubes I finally figured out the perfect settings.

Apparently, the extrusion width in my slicer was set to a certain number, instead of 
percentage. I was printing at 0.45 mm extrusion width, which was ~105 % of the 0.4 mm nozzle diameter, but less than 50 % of the 0.8 mm one. Changing the value to 130-140 % 
solved the majority of my printing problems.

As I predicted, the 230-280 ℃ nozzle temp. was ridiculously high, even with the 
0.8 mm nozzle.  I gradually lowered it to 210 ℃ (ironically, the value I chose at the very beginning).

There was some warping, so I cleaned the heatbed from the glue, put the glue again and decreased bed temp. to 50 ℃

Finally, I decreased the flow from 1.3 to 1.05 and everything seems perfect now.

Comment: Nice that you shared your solution, this was hard to guess based on your question! This proves that stating all the print settings is a must for solving print problems. Your small extrusion width in combination with the large flow modifier mimics the wider extrusion width, but fails to do a proper job. +1 from me! *Note that I still find 100 mm/s to be fast for a 0.8 mm nozzle, but of it works, go for it!*

Comment: @0scar Thank you! I found that larger prints required higher temperature/different settings, but luckily the most important part is done.